# Intercept events on modal feature in Magento 2

Tags: modal-dialog, magento2

I need to intercept the "closed" event for a Modal popup in Magento 2 but i don't know where and how to do it.

This is the script within the template file, it works great but, as i wrote, i need to intercept the closed event to stop the video play.

```js
<script>
    require(
            [
                'jquery',
                'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
            ],
            function ($, modal) {
                var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                    title: $.mage.__('Title Text'),
                    buttons: [{
                            text: $.mage.__('Close'),
                            class: '',
                            click: function () {
                                this.closeModal();
                                var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
                                video.pause();
                            }
                        }]
                };
                var popup = modal(options, $('#modalVideo'));
                $("#modalVideoOpen").on("click", function () {
                    $('#modalVideo').modal('openModal');
                    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
                    video.play();
                });
            }
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#modalVideoOpen').data('mage-modal').modal.on('modalclosed', function(){console.log('closed')})
```

The modal widget triggers 'closed' event and as [jquery doc](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/) says "the event type is determined by concatenating the plugin name and the callback name", we should subscribe on 'modalclosed'

Answer (score 2):

you can also specify it in the options :

```js
var options = {
    type: 'popup',
    responsive: true,
    title: $.mage.__('Title Text'),
    closed: function (e) {
        // fun here!
    }
};
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work, the code inside is never called.

Comment: The option name is `closed`. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html#modal_events

Comment: the only problem with this is it works on all closed event, instead of weather the popup was closed by clicking on close button of the popup or through programmatically.